# GNotifier broke my Thunderbird profile

Tags: thunderbird, plugin

I installed the GNotifier extension to Thunderbird.  The resulting notifications did not leave a persistent sign anywere in the GNOME desktop interface, which is what I installed GNotifier for.

When I removed GNotifier, I stopped receiving email popup notifications.  I tried reinstalling GNotifier, resetting the notification type to Thunderbirds default, and removing GNotifier again, but for some reason that didn't seem to work for me either.

I don't want to wipe my Thunderbird profile, but I want my mail notifications back!  Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferences -> Advanced -> Config Editor

Reset `mail.biff.show_alert`. After resetting it, the value will be `true`.

---

There were so many "user set" preferences, I had to search for "notif" and then "alert" before I found the problem.

("[biff is a mail notification system for UNIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biff)", in case you're puzzled where than name comes from).